# Getting the inherited property of a Control's RightToLeft

Tags: c#, winforms

#### Background

In `WinForms App Control` there is an `AmbientProperty` of an enum called `RightToLeft`.
Now this enum has three options: `Yes`, `No` and `Inherits`  .
The problem is when ever I need to figure out the exact value of the `RightToLeft` prop', I'm getting stack with the `Inherits` options.

#### The Question

Is there any way to retrieve the value from the control's parents or the control itself and end up with `true`/`false` rather than an annoying enum?

Comment: As LukeSw points out below, the RightToLeft property never returns "Inherit".  There is probably more to this question than you're letting on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private bool IsRightToLeft(Control c){       
   if(c.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Inherit){
      return (c.Parent != null) ? IsRightToLeft(c.Parent) : false;
      //I think if the Control has no Parent, its Default RightToLeft is Inherit.
   }
   else return c.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes;
}
```

Or use extension method:

```
public static class ControlExtension {
   public static bool IsRightToLeft(this Control c){
      return c.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Inherit ? (c.Parent != null ? IsRightToLeft(c.Parent) : false) : c.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes;
   }
}
```

### UPDATE

Here is another solution which may be simpler although it uses a win32 function called `GetWindowLong`, the whole idea is if `RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes`, the `Control` will have the style `WS_EX_RIGHT = 0x1000`, otherwise `RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No` (In fact, `RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Inherit` means it may be `Yes` or `No`, the default I see mostly is `No` - meaning Left to right).

```
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex);
public static class ControlExtension {
   public static bool IsRightToLeft(this Control c){
     return (GetWindowLong(c.Handle,-20) & 0x1000) != 0;//GWL_EXSTYLE = -20
   }
}
```

I think this is better than the one I posted before. :)

Comment: Yup, it did the work.
I need get that recursive pattern into my coding habits, thanks.

Comment: @NucS see my update with another choice for you to implement the method `IsRightToLeft()` returning `bool`.

Comment: You don’t have to check parent control, the RightToLeft property getter do it itself. You can verify that with Reflector.

Answer (score 3):

RightToLeft getter returns only Yes or No value, you'll never get Inherit value.

Quote from MSDN:

> If you assign a value of Inherit to the RightToLeft property, the value returned will be the setting of the RightToLeft property of the parent control. If there is no parent control, it will return a value of No.

Comment: How did you know this yourself? with some search after reading the question or you've learnt it before? it's interesting to know this. In fact I did not even try/test what the OP said about the possibility of receiving the `Inherit` value, also +1 for the answer, too late but totally correct. However this problem is not some kind of very serious.

Comment: I've checked with Reflector after reading the question, because I suspected that 'inherit' should work like in CSS.